# Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values pandas error

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
key      system      impl_date
1        madison     2021-01-27T13:16:18.000-0600
2        madison     2021-01-27T13:15:04.000-0600
3        lexington   2021-01-27T13:08:27.000-0600
4        park        2021-01-27T13:05:42.000-0600
```

The `impl_date` column contains strings because earlier in the script I apply the following:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

I want to take the `impl_date` column and strip the time element, resulting in a date that takes the following form:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I used the following:

```
df['impl_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['impl_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
AttributeError:  Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I tried the following:

```
df['impl_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['impl_date'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This fails with the same error message.

`df.dtypes` gives the following:

```
key         object
system      object
impl_date   object
type:  object
```

`type(df)` gives:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

And, `df.info()` gives:

```
#  Column      Non-Null Count   Dtype
-  ------      --------------   -----
0  key         6453 non-null    object
1  system      6453 non-null    object
2  impl_date   6453 non-null    object
```

Given that the `impl_date` is represented as a string, what's the best way to transform this column to a `yyyy-dd-mm` format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data may contain different timezones, like this:

```
key      system      impl_date
1        madison     2021-01-27T13:16:18.000-0600
2        madison     2021-01-27T13:15:04.000-0600
3        lexington   2021-01-27T13:08:27.000-0600
5        park        2021-01-27T13:05:42.000-0500   # here
```

Option is to pass `utc=True` to `to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['impl_date'], errors='coerce', utc=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And you get:

```
0    2021-01-27
1    2021-01-27
2    2021-01-27
3    2021-01-27
Name: impl_date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem